# Unwanted redirection from 433 to https

Tags: redirect, iis, https

An unwanted redirection happens on the host server if I browsed for https it redirects me to HTTP and notices that I haven't any redirection rule to HTTP. the odd thing is that I can browse my app in https from any other device it works well, but not from the host itself. Another thing to notice is that I can bind the site to any other https port and it works well from anywhere, but I want to use the default https port.
I'm using IIS 8.

so any help on this issue?!

Comment: Can you please show us redirect rules what you have in web.config?

Comment: @VictorLeontyev I don't have any rules in web.config

Comment: Maybe your browser cached old redirect. Can you please clear your cache and try again

Comment: @VictorLeontyev that was right.. Thanks

Comment: I've posted it as an answer. Can you please accept it, if it's working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers are caching redirects. You need to clear your browser's cache and try again